# R - lapply several functions in one lapply by elements

Tags: r, lapply

In R, when I run two functions in `lapply`, it runs the first function on the entire list, then run the second function on the list. Is it possible to force it runs both functions on the first element on the list before moving onto the second element?

I am using the function `print` and `nchar` for **illustration purpose** -- I wrote more complex functions that generate data.frame.

```
  lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) {
    print(x)
    nchar(x)
  })
```

the output would be

```
[1] "a"
[1] "bb"
[1] "cdd"
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "bb"
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] "cdd"
[1] 3
```

is this possible?

Juan Antonio Roladan Diaz and cash2 both suggested using `list`, which kind of works:

```
lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) { 
  list(x, nchar(x))
})

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "bb"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "cdd"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3
```

But it is a bit too messy.

using print gives a better result,

```
lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) { 
  print(x)
  print(nchar(x))
  })

[1] "a"
[1] 1
[1] "bb"
[1] 2
[1] "cdd"
[1] 3
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

but is there a way to suppress `nchar` from being print out again?

Comment: You can get something similar: `lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) list(x, nchar(x))); lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) c(x, nchar(x)))`

Comment: `nchar` is vectorized. Maybe you do not need the `lapply` at all.

Comment: @mt1022, thanks, but nchar was for illustration purpose only... I have a function that generates a matrix...

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz, thanks, list works, c doesn't, but the output is very clumsy... I now revise my question a little bit...

Comment: Try this: invisible(lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) { 
  print(x)
  print(nchar(x))
}))

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz, it works. can you put that as answer so i can accept it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
invisible(lapply(c("a","bb","cdd"), function(x) { print(x); print(nchar(x)) }))
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the function prints x, then returns `nchar(x)`; the returned elements are put into a list by `lapply` and returned, and printed out on the REPL.

Replace `nchar(x)` with `print(nchar(x))`. Or, if you want the list returned, just return `list(x, nchar(x))` from the inner function.

Comment: they both works, thanks! Wondering if there are cleaner solutions. seems the best way to write another function to merge the two functions if there are no cleaner output...